# " File ended while scanning use of \next..." causes by the use of a multilines newcommand

Tags: macros

Error while using the new command \reponse created in the preambule.

What is wrong with the definition of the newcommand ?  It must be linked with comment package ...

Example that works seems the same : [How to use `\begin` & `\end` in a new command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272008/how-to-use-begin-end-in-a-new-command)

Thanks for help.

Error : File ended while scanning use of \next \end{answer} while using the commande \reponse

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\includecomment{answer}
\newcommand{\reponse}[1]{%
\begin{answer}
{\textbf{The answer is :}#1}
\end{answer}}


\begin{document}
% i would like to write :
\reponse{ok}
\reponse{ok}
% ...
% instead of :
\begin{answer}
{\textbf{The answer is:} ok}
\end{answer}                       <- error line 
\begin{answer}
{\textbf{The answer is:} ok}
\end{answer}
%...

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't use “comment environments” as arguments to commands, just like you can't with `verbatim`: a comment environment is treated the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @egreg said, you can not use `comment` environment as arguments.
The difficulty comes from a special condition given in the package documentation: *The opening and closing commands should appear on a line of their own. No starting spaces, nothing after it.*

But here is what I can suggest (The trick comes from section *2 Usage* of the `comment` documentation):

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{babel}
\includecomment{answer}
\makeatletter 
\newcommand{\reponse}[1]{\@bsphack\@esphack}
\makeatother 
\begin{answer}
\renewcommand{\reponse}[1]{\textbf{The answer is :}#1}
\end{answer}


\begin{document}
% i would like to write :
\reponse{ok}
\reponse{ok}
% ...
% instead of :
\begin{answer}
{\textbf{The answer is:} ok}
\end{answer}

\begin{answer}
{\textbf{The answer is:} ok}
\end{answer}
%...
\end{document}
```

**EDIT** Taking into account UlrichDiez's comment.

Comment: Nice logic to create an empty new command, and optionaly (if answer is set) modify it with a renew command !

Comment: In case `\response` doesn't print anything - shouldn't it preserve the space-factor? -- I.e., `\makeatletter \newcommand{\reponse}[1]{\@bsphack\@esphack}\makeatother \begin{answer}\renewcommand{\reponse}[1]{\textbf{The answer is:} #1}\end{answer}` (By the way: I think the blank space should be behind the colon, not before it.)

Comment: You're right @UlrichDiez. Even if I do not think the code will be used for in-line comments, it looks better taking into account your comment.